# Can I know a method which is equivalent to "HttpServerUtility.MapPath" in silverlight(xaml)

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, server.mappath

I want a method which is equivalent to `""HttpServerUtility.MapPath"` in silverlight(xaml) which returns the physical file path that corresponds to the specified virtual path.

In Web app i used:

```
LocalPath = Server.MapPath("~/default.aspx");
```

But i will be unable to use the same in xaml as `system.web` assembly does not exist here.

Thanks.

Comment: Clearly it does not exist as each server is different and client side code have no information about server side file system mappings (if any)... Could you please provide sample of input/output you expect from that magical function? (and possibly usage scenario)

Comment: This is almost exactly the sample of your post - so does not provide any clarification from my point of view... I.e. I read "local" as "on machine that runs the code" (which is one where browser runs or phone) but you trying to show some server side path ("~/default.aspx" or "~app/..."). I hope someone else would understand what you are saying.

Comment: @Alexei : I would like to use something like this :                       LocalPath = Server.MapPath("~/app/appName.apk"); So that i get the path of the apk which is present in my workspace. After getting the path i would download the apk from that path. Is this possible?

Comment: @Alexei  : Im so sorry due to my internet prob my comment got posted before i completely write.

Comment: @anjali Check if this helps - http://www.markusegger.com/blog/Blog.aspx?blogid=6a0addce-851e-4579-9306-0297254a1473&messageid=4f13df72-ee59-4a36-aa08-c582d9cad56d

Comment: @ Amar Duplantier : Thanks for the link. It doesn't help me because i have a method to download. What i need is the method which can convert the virtual path in the app to the physical path.

Comment: Side note: I'm somewhat puzzled how you plan to use something like "c:\files\app\appName.apk" from the client... It may be good idea for you to think about how different items are addressed from browser and server to clarify how you want to achieve your goal.